# Chrome Extension Manifest v3 - editing response header depending on certain features of that header

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, http-headers, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to migrate a Chrome extension to Manifest v3.

Essentially, the extension does the following for every response from every website:

1. If there is no `Content-Security-Policy` header, it does nothing else.
2. Otherwise, it analyses the CSP header, and, if neither the report-uri directive, nor the report-to directive are present, it does nothing else.
3. Otherwise, it checks the value of `[script-src, script-src-elem, script-src-attr, style-src, style-src-elem, style-src-attr]`, ignoring the ones that are not present.
4. Then, for every directive in the above list, if `'report-sample'` is not included in the value, it injects it, in order to enhance the reporting capabilities.

Before Manifest v3, all of the above was achieved via `onHeadersReceived()`, thanks to the `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions.

Apparently `webRequestBlocking` is not a thing anymore, and I am supposed to use Declarative Net Requests instead.

However, DNRs do not support (as far as I understand) the kind of header inspection + modification that the extension needs to perform.

What I think I need is the following:

- A way to programmatically specify the conditions 1), 2), and 3) in DNR syntax.
- A way to get and edit the CSP header according to 4) in DNR syntax.
- A way to substitute the old header with the new one.

I think I know how to do the latter. However, the first two points still elude me.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

P.S., I tried to use `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules()`, but that does not help me, if I am not able to get the CSP header, analyse it, and modify it if needed.

Comment: There's no solution yet other than force-installing the extension to keep using webRequestBlocking. Consider describing your use case in https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions so that Chrome team knows the negative consequences of their decision. Currently the team genuinely thinks DNR is a sufficient replacement. The more people say otherwise, the higher the chance there'll be a solution.